# Merge SQL Rows in Subquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to work with two tables on BigQuery. From table1 I want to find the accession ID of all records that are "World", and then from each of those accession numbers I want to create a column with every name in a separate row. Unfortunately, when I run this:

```
Select name
From `table2` 
Where acc IN (Select acc
                From `table1`
                WHERE source = 'World')
```

Instead of getting something like this:

| Acc1 | Acc2 | Acc3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jeff | Jeff | Ted |
| Chris | Ted | Blake |
|  | Rob | Jack |
|  | Jack |  |

I get something more like this:

| row | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jeff |
| 2 | Chris |
| 3 | Rob |
| 4 | Jack |
| 5 | Jeff |
| 6 | Jack |
| 7 | Ted |
| 8 | Blake |

Ultimately, I am hoping to download the data and somehow use python or something to take each name and count the number of times it shows up with each other name at a given accession number, and furthermore measure the degree to which each pairing is also found with third names in any given column, i.e. the degree to which they share a cohort. So I need to preserve the groupings which exist with each accession number, but I am struggling to find info on how one might do this.

Could anybody point me in the right direct for this, or otherwise is the way I am going about this wise if that is my end goal?

Thanks!

Comment: What does your data look like?  Do you know the list of "accession numbers" in the final result?

Comment: you need to use pivot() - https://hoffa.medium.com/easy-pivot-in-bigquery-one-step-5a1f13c6c710

Comment: no way to answer this question without sample of input and expected output! please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to the question you asked.  In general, it is easier to handle multiple rows rather than multiple columns.

So, I would recommend that you put each `acc` value in a separate row and then list the names as an *array*:

```
select t2.acc, array_agg(t2.name order by t2.name) as names
from `table2` t2
where t2.acc in (Select t1.acc
                 From `table1` t1
                 where t1.source = 'World'
                )
group by t2.acc;
```

Otherwise, you are going to have a challenge just naming the columns in your result set.